# Transpose series in looping dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data and I want to get maxium value in each 11 rows. There only problem is I cant transpose the result of max function. As you can see in `print(res2.transpose())` the result still

```
A    3
B    6
C    9
D    5
dtype: int64
A    6
B    5
C    6
D    9
dtype: int64
A    5
B    6
C    9
D    9
dtype: int64
A    9
B    9
C    9
D    6
dtype: int64
```

but what  I excepted is

```
A B C D
3 6 9 5
A B C D
6 5 6 9
A B C D
5 6 9 9    
A B C D
9 9 9 6
```

So in `nilai_max`
The result should be :

```
A B C D
3 6 9 5
6 5 6 9
5 6 9 9    
9 9 9 6
```

I think the problem in `res2`, I can't transpose the sereies.
Here the code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
                     'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
                     'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
                     'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
                    )
cek_baris = len(data.index)

nilai_max = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(int(cek_baris/11)):
    jml_baris=11
    res2 =data[i*jml_baris:(i+1)*jml_baris].max()
    print(res2.transpose())
    if nilai_max.empty:
        nilai_max = res2
    else:
        nilai_max = nilai_max.append(res2)    
print(nilai_max)
```

Comment: What is jml_baris ?

Comment: sorry, missing code. Updated

Comment: @Gozally Will nilai_max.tail(4) does the job?

Comment: @N.Arunoprayoch sorry for my mistake, I didn't show whole result before. So many miss understand here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use [max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) with `axis=1`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
...                      'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
...                      'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
...                      'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
...                     )
>>> df = df.max(axis=1)
>>> df
0     7
1     8
2     9
... (you get the idea) ...
41    9
42    9
43    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: axis = 1 gives you the max in a single row across columns. axis = 0 will give the max of numbers in a single column across rows. In this case, axis = 0 is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My result of max is what i excepted, but the problem is how to transpose my result. because when I store in new variable it becomes series.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9],
                 'B':[9],
                 'C':[9],
                 'D':[6]}
                )
new_sample = sample.T
```

The above code snippet provides the output you mentioned in the question. Here is the transpose of the whole dataframe after getting the maximum of each column:

The 'data' dataframe has four columns with respective maximum values of 9 in all which is calculated using max(axis=0). This provides a Series output. Convert it to a dataframe and perform transpose on it to get your desired output.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2],
                 'B':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,3,5,1,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,2],
                 'C':[7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,1,3,5,4],
                 'D':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,4,1,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,6,4,3,6,3]}
                )
max_data = data.max(axis = 0).reset_index()
max_data = max_data.set_index('index')
max_data = max_data.T
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this function, it works fine if I understand correctly.

**Function**

```
def create_new_df(my_series):
    column_names = my_series.index.unique().tolist()
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i, j in zip(column_names, zip(*[iter(my_series)] * len(column_names))):
        new_df[i] = j

    return new_df

# Call function
new_df = create_new_df(nilai_max)
new_df
```

**Result:**

```
    A   B   C   D
0   3   6   5   9
1   6   5   6   9
2   9   6   9   9
3   5   9   9   6
```